# If I change the sim in my iPad4 (retina) will I have to set it up again?

Tags: ios, sim, ipad, setup

I've changed providers and gotten a cheaper plan for my iPad. (Running iOS 7)

My question is: **If I change the sim in my iPad4 (retina) will I have to set it up again?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would have to just set up the new provider stuff.

Account with them, email if you have one, the data plan, the payment service ect.